# empty() and magic method __get()

Tags: php

The situation I have is not complicated but it took me a while to figure it.

```
class A {

    private $data = array('key' => 'value');

    public function __get($name){
        return $this->data[$name];
    }

}

$a = new A();
var_dump(empty($a->key)); // TRUE
```

I suppose this is because `empty` checks the class structure for some reason instead of running the code inside the brackets. Why is it not evaluating this code as expected?

Is this a bug or why is it not working properly?

Comment: You shouldn't use `return $data[$name];` but `return $this->data[$name];`, I guess?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware well yeah I just wrote that for the question, simple mistake. Will fix it, thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, in PHP you need to use `$this->` in order to access class variables like your `$data` (so `$this->data` instead of `$data`). It's easy to forget after working with another language for a while, but in case you're not developing your code with error-reporting set to `E_ALL`, you should set it to that. Having it set to `E_ALL` during development allows you to more easily find (potential) bugs such as this one and will improve your code quality.

To address your real issue, in order to determine if a variable is-set for magic variables, you need to add the `__isset` magic method ([manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.isset)):

```
<?php

class A {

    private $data = array('key' => 'value');

    public function __get($name){
        return $this->data[$name];
    }
    public function __isset($name){
        return array_key_exists($name, $this->data);
    }

}

$a = new A();
var_dump(empty($a->key)); // it's FALSE now
```

Comment: The part about `$this`, I'm sorry I just wrote this bit of code just for the question and it was a simple mistake, apologies. Thanks!

Comment: It's a common mistake of mine while switching between C# and PHP. ;) If you're learning about magic methods, I suggest taking a peek at [this class](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/base/CComponent.php#L177); I really love the way that works (it's a bit complicated though).

Comment: I wonder, though, if this method is so straight-forward, why isn't it implemented automatically? I mean I just had to write `function __isset($name){ return isset($this->data[$name]); }`. I wonder why they haven't configured it to run that by default :?

Comment: @php_nub_qq Because get is very different from isset. You can't simply wrap isset around a get call because that's a dangerous assumption. isset is supposed to be a very lite call to check if it exists. get could be a heavy/expensive call that actually fetches all the data, processes it, then returns it.